How can I safely cut cultured countertops containing silica?
I was not aware until recently that dust from concrete and from countertops is almost insanely dangerous (silica..)
When trying to make a cut in a cultured quartz countertop I was shocked by how virulent the dust is. I was wearing two N95 masks and outside but a tiny bit of the dust from a few seconds of grinding (router) really bothered me.
Presently I am at a loss as to how to cut this stuff. Depositing the dust in my garage or on my driveway or anywhere is just not a great idea: it blows around.  Do I put together some kind of hermetically sealed area in the garage maybe?  I do have a ventilator (as well as a respirator).  Is there any way to work with this stuff outside of a professional fabrication facility?
The tools I've tried (and all make prolific dust)

cutoff wheel with diamond blade
circular saw with diamond blade
wet saw with diamond blade
router with carbide bit

I do run a vacuum and ventilator at the same time. But it's not enough.  Any tips on this?  At this point I have forfeited on the concept of cutting out the sinks. I just want to make one lateral straight cut of 24 inches and be done.

It is not insanely dangerous, it is mildly hazardous.

@Stian My lungs from one deep exposure wish your inaccurate information were actually correct. Look up silicosis.

Still only hazardous. An whiff of something insanely dangerous will kill you on the spot. And in either case, a good mask, used properly and a habit of not smoking will fix the problem completely.

@Stian. I always wear two masks (layered) when indoors doing construction.  That was proven to be completely insufficient when I got that blast of dust (two or three minutes when I was doing  measurements) .  It made me feel terrible for several days.  I still have a frog in my throat six weeks later.    I am a runner and have never smoked anything in my life.

Those type of countertops are routinely cut with wet saws. The operator should also have eye, ear, breathing and skin protection.
A proper amount of water should result in a mud and not dust.  The mud can be cleaned up and disposed of in the same manner as any other harmful waste.       ( Think of pet waste.)
Silica is dangerous if exposed in large amount or over long term.  Wearing the proper protection should make you safe, or you can hire someone to cut the top for you.

Even wet saws can produce some dust, but much less than cutting dry.  Contractor installed mortarless brick on my house.  Created a lot of gooey mud, but still a bit of dust in the air.

I have used a 7 inch and 14 inch wet saw on concrete with excessive water  but it still throws clouds of dust. Yes there is mud there too (so it helps moderately).  Maybe there are specific details of the process that I could improve on ..

"Large amounts".  A single concentrated exposure has affected me for the past month.  And I was wearing two N95's (but with inadequate ventilation)

When I cut the countertop yesterday a lot of dust was generated even with dousing liberally and frequently with water.  A sprayer is arriving from Amazon within a couple of hours. I'm done with the countertop at this point but will try out the sprayer anyways on a remnant.  You said that the dust should be much less for countertops than for concrete: I'll give it a shot.

My actual process.  I did make the cuts in this super tough material.  I staked out an enclosed area that would not send dust everywhere and did the following:

[Mostly] Enclosed the cutting area (beneath my arms) with a clear plastic painting drop cloth . So there was plastic [as well as the masks] between my lungs and the lion's share of the dust.

Set up powerful shop vac inside that enclosed area inches from the circular saw

Since it was a standard circular saw [and not my wet saw] I doused the cutting area with water and regularly added more to the cut as I went.  I've done this in the past for cutting concrete. It's bit messy but setting up the wet saw takes more time [and it's a 14 inch blade so it's pretty unwieldy for anything but heavy concrete cutting]

Set up a ventilator (the red-orange serpent thing). I've had this for years. It comes out of storage every now and again and I'm glad to have it in those moments

Set up two high speed fans to blow air from the main room into that area

I donned four masks: a kn95 and then three N95's.  If nothing else the restricted breathing reminds me not to spend too much time in there [*]!



The cuts did come out fine. They were just straight cuts so the only thing needed was for the guards not to slip and to keep a steady hand on the circular saw (while adding water and adjusting the vacuum hose).  I ducked out to get fresh air a number of times.  And had to flip the circuit breaker three times since the diamond blade was just barely enough to work through this "nearly hard as granite" material.
In the end the cuts were done and safely. But that was quite an effort at setup.  I think the most transferable learning here were the use of the plastic dropcloth to nearly seal the dusted area. I don't expect to typically have the luxury of a ventilator or two high speed fans.

@RMDman. I did that for laminate countertops that are simply wood and not dangerous. The whole point here is to contain the silica dust.  I do not have a setup to do that with sawhorses . Even outside the dust spreads which is something I want to avoid  for various reasons.

@RMDman. The point of this question is to elicit details on how to avoid the dust. Just a wet saw does not cut it.  The water reduces the dust but even 40% of the dust is well too much .  To say there is "no danger" is simply not accurate.

OK I am going on my past experience of the 14 inch wet saw on concrete.  I will try out that monster on a remnant of that cultured quartz just to see

@RMDman Yes. It's a PITA to set up and did not fare one iota better than the standard circular saw on concrete [when I doused it regularly and liberally with water spray ]. What I'm hearing from you is that concrete and quartz [and similar] are quite different in terms of throwing dust. I have not noticed that [plenty of dust in the latter as well] but am willing to give it a try.

[when I doused it regularly and liberally with water spray with my free hand!]   If you are not using a saw that has a continuous water jet spraying water on what you are cutting then you will have dust.   A wet saw is only working as a WET saw when it has the proper water supply.  Throwing some water with a free hand will NOT cut it, ( no pun)   I think we found out why you have a dust issue.

@RDMan. I had already addressed your comment in prior ones. For example look at the comment from 3 minutes before yours that I did use a full-on wet saw for concrete (with continuous water source) and the dust mitigation was no different than my manual approach.   The only thing I have to go on here is your comment that the quartz/stone materials have substantially different behavior for throwing dust [than quartz/stone].  And I already mentioned I will try the wet saw on a quart remnant (earlier comment).
